# I want to get values of text boxes or the text in them , JavaScript using phonon framework

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have tried

```
Var xy=document.getElementById('Textboxid);
phonon.alert(xy);
```

But it doesn't work. Yet it normally works when using materialize and jQuery.

Comment: If you want to get the value, Use `document.getElementById('Textboxid').value;` also you have missed quotation after `Textboxid`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value, Use `document.getElementById('Textboxid').value`; also you have missed quotation after `Textboxid`

**Like this:**

```js
var y = document.getElementById('txt').value;
alert(y);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt" value="text" />
```